# Is Python list essentially a linked-list implementation?

Tags: python, list, memory

Wondering what I can infer from the below statements?

```
>>> li=['a', 'b']
>>> id(li)
4300601032
>>> li.insert(0,'Z')
>>> li
['Z', 'a', 'b']
>>> id(li)
4300601032
```

Is the original list object copied before inserting 'Z' or does it work like a linked-list?

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable):

> List and bytearray objects support additional operations that allow in-place modification of the object.

`insert` is listed as one of those operations.  So no copy is made, and `insert` modifies the list object in place.

Note that this has no bearing on how lists are implemented.  Whether lists are implemented as linked lists is not part of what is specified by the documentation.  All that is specified is what the various operations *do*, not how they are done.